# Как понять поведение _getche()

Tags: c

Использую данную функцию для ввода символов. Насколько я знаю, символ  `'\t'`
включает в себя 8 пробелов. Данная функция это доказала, но, как оказалось, не всегда(?)
Простой пример: запустить приложение с циклом и вводить символы в консоль через эту функцию. Ввести, к примеру, 10 единичек. И следом нажать *tab*. Так вот, программа не отпечатает 8 пробелов. Их будет меньше. Следующее нажатие *tab* послушно печатает отступ, шириной 8 пробелов. Чем вызвано такое поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Табулятор - это **не** конкретное количество пробелов, а выравнивание следующего выводимого символа до указанного количества.

Причем это зависит от настроек конкретной среды/редактора - какое именно выравнивание использовать.

В вашем примере, если табуляции выровнены на 8 символов, то после вывода 10 единиц до следующей табуляции (16) останется 6 пустых мест...

`_getche()` тут вообще в полной мере ни при чем... Как, собственно, и язык C.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, не знал этого вовсе. Вы очень помогли

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый :)

Comment: форум не давал, вот только теперь можно)